# Running functions in a vector using TBB gives incorrect output

Tags: c++, function, parallel-processing, tbb

Here is my code which is supposed to write the numbers 0 to 19 on the screen (in random order).

```
vector<std::function<void(void)>> tasks;
for(int i=0; i<20;i++)
     { 
        tasks.push_back( [&](){cout<< i<<endl;} );  
     }

tbb::parallel_for(size_t(0), size_t(tasks.size()), [&](int K) {(tasks[K])();});
```

The out out is:

```
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it to write out the numbers 0 to 19?

Comment: What's `K` on the last line?

Comment: I added declaration.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed a *reference* to `i` when adding the new task:

> ```
>    tasks.push_back( [&](){cout<< i<<endl;} );  
>    //               ^^^ here
> ```

When the task is run, `i` has reached 20, so that's what each thread will print.

Instead, you probably want to capture a *copy* of `i`:

```
    tasks.push_back([=i]{ std::cout << i << '\n'; });
```

(The `=` is optional there; I included it to make the point clearer)